# Eye detection software

Tags: eye-detection

I need an eye-detection software having good accuracy. The software should be able to detect eye coordinates on still images. 
Can anybody give me good suggestions regarding the same.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try OpenCV? It has simple functions for eye detecting and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Eye detection works best when the program first detects the faces, and then search within the faces to detect the eyes. Here is a tutorial on how it's done using OpenCV:

http://nashruddin.com/opencv_eye_detection

Comment: This is no longer live

Answer (score 0):

it's open source lib for gaze tracking: http://gazegroup.org/downloads/23-gazetracker

Comment: Its for tracking live eye i.e. tracking when the webcam is on.. I was unable to find if it also works on still jpeg images ?